# How to find the status of each keyword execution in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I want to get the status, elapsed time, arguments of each keyword execution in robot framework in runtime instead of getting it in the output.xml

Comment: Welcome at [so]. It is expected that questions meet certain criteria. These are described in the [ask] page that I strongly suggest you read. In addition we expect a certain level of effort to already have been spent on your part. This is typically done by showing us the code that you're working on and providing us with some details on the expected and observed results.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) by creating a class that implements the `end_keyword` method.

Here's an example that prints the results to stdout:

```
class ResultStreamer(object):
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

    def end_keyword(self, name, attrs):
        message = "%s  status: %s elapsed: %sms" % (
            attrs['kwname'],
            attrs['status'],
            attrs['elapsedtime']
        )
        print(message)
```

If you save that to a file named `ResultStreamer.py`, you can use it on the command line like this:

```
robot --listener ResultStreamer.py my_test.robot
```